# How to concatenate a mixed list of 1d and 0d numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to concatenate a list of arrays which is a mix of zero and one dimensional arrays. They are a result of `genfromtxt` on some output files. The minimal example which breaks for me is as follows:

```
from numpy import array, concatenate
array1 = array([1.0, 2.0])
array2 = array(3.0)
concatenate([array1, array2])
```

This code produces an error:

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Is there any way to concatenate in a single line a list of 1d and 0d? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add dimension(s) to the smaller one. Also make sure the dtypes match.

Comment: @hpaulj, the mismatch of dimensions is on purpose. Should I add it to the description? The motivation for this comes because output from genfromtxt on a collection of files gives a list of 0d or 1d arrays.

Comment: What sort of file produces a 0d array?

Comment: @hpaulj a file which only contains one entry in one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python provides a function [`atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) so to solve the problem

```
from numpy import array, concatenate, atleast_1d
array1 = array([1.0, 2.0])
array2 = array(3.0)
concatenate([atleast_1d(a) for a in [array1, array2]])
```

and in my original problem

```
concatenate([atleast_1d(a) for a in mixed_list])
```

would solve the concatenation issue.

Comment: `concatenate([a.ravel() for a in [array1, array2]])` does the same but more than twice as fast.

Comment: You are both right and in both cases it would result in cleaner code. I think I like `hstack` better. Is it ok to improve an answer that has already been voted on?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array(3)
```

Add a dimension then stack

```
>>> np.hstack([a, b[None,]])
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> np.hstack([a, b.reshape(1)])
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1)))
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score -1):

you forgot *[ ]* when you declared second array

```
from numpy import array, concatenate
array1 = array([1.0, 2.0])
array2 = array([3.0])
print(concatenate([array1, array2]))
```

output:

```
[1. 2. 3.]
```

Comment: Hi William, that was the point of the example. The 0 dimensional array was generate by `genfromtxt`.